# Finding a cycle in a directed graph (Tideman cs50)

Tags: c#, graph

I know similar questions have been asked and perhaps this method simply takes too long with a large candidate set however...

I have a directed graph with N nodes where N is about 150.  Thus the nodes are represented by contiguous integer 0 to N-1.

The edges of the graph are defined in a Boolean array:
bool locked[n, m] = true where edge n->m exists.

I know the initial state of the graph is acyclic and I want to see if adding an edge creates a cycle.

Potential edges to be added are in an array of pairs, where a pair is a struct {int winner int loser}
Thus:  pairs[x].source  is the xth potential edge’s source.

What is an efficient code to check if adding the edge creates a cycle?  Here is what I am trying now, but it appears to run MUCH too slowly, and does not seem to ever find a cycle.  (I have seen certain pair adds take over 20 million nestedLevels called.)

```
    private void lockPairs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Program.pairCount-1; i++)
        {
            // don't add an edge if it will make the graph form a cycle
            Console.WriteLine(Program.nestedLevels);
            Program.nestedLevels = 0;
            if (!hasCycle(Program.pairs[i].winner, Program.pairs[i].loser))
            {
                Program.locked[Program.pairs[i].winner , Program.pairs[i].loser] = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Locked");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NotLocked");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the hasCycle check.

```
private bool hasCycle(int winner, int loser)
    {
        Program.nestedLevels++;
        if (Program.locked[loser,winner])
        {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Program.numCandidate; i++)
        {
            if (Program.locked[loser,i] && hasCycle(winner, i))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks.  I had found that info and may try to implement it, but was put off from the number of comments stating it does not return correct results.